CSRF and JWT With Sping Security 6 Stateless REST
I have a question about how to incorporate JWT tokens with CSRF protection when integrating  with the Angular framework and Spring security 6. While there numerous posts on whether to use both CSRF and JWT, the intent is to seek advice on how to implement both and understand expected behavior. I have been following the SPRING DOCS here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration-javascript
The most common answer to this is to disable csrf because it is stateless but to some extent state is maintained by the front end UI.
My application is experiencing the following behavior and I do not know how to get around it.

Upon a successful login, an XSRF-TOKEN cookie is created in the
browser
After any operation (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE), the cookie is
unset
Since the cookie is unset, I can no longer perform any unsafe
operations like a POST, PUT or DELETE till a new cookie is set by
performing a GET (considered a safe operation).

What is the correct way to constantly refresh the csrf cookie?
The following are my project configurations
@Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler crsfTokenRequestHandler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
        http
        //.securityContext(contextConfig -> contextConfig.requireExplicitSave(false)) // removed and only used for JSESSIONID
        .sessionManagement(sessionConfig-> sessionConfig.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .cors(corsConfig -> corsConfig.configurationSource(new CorsConfigurationSource() {
            @Override
            public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request) {
                CorsConfiguration myconfig = new CorsConfiguration();
                myconfig.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
                myconfig.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                myconfig.setAllowCredentials(true);
                myconfig.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                myconfig.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));
                myconfig.setMaxAge(3600L);
                return myconfig;
            }
        }))
        //.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                
                  .csrf(csrfConfig ->
                  csrfConfig.csrfTokenRequestHandler(crsfTokenRequestHandler)
                  .ignoringRequestMatchers(REGISTER_URL, H2_CONSOLE_URL)
                  .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()))
                  
        .addFilterAfter(new JWTTokenGeneratorFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)      
        .addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(new JWTTokenValidationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .requiresChannel(rcc -> rcc.anyRequest().requiresInsecure())
        .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .requestMatchers(H2_CONSOLE_URL).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(REGISTER_URL, "/error", "/invalidSession").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(LOGIN_URL,OCCASSIONS_LIST_URL, OCCASSION_GET, OCCASSIONS_EDIT, OCCASIONS_ADD, USER_GET, USER_EDIT).authenticated())
        .headers(h -> h.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::sameOrigin));
        //http.formLogin(flc -> flc.disable()); // this is a login page with a user name and password using Spring MVC
        http.formLogin(withDefaults());
        http.httpBasic(hbc -> hbc.authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint())); // this is header based
        http.exceptionHandling(ehc -> ehc.accessDeniedHandler(new CustomAccessDeniedHandler()));
        return http.build();
    }


@Toerktumlare please don't panic or get discouraged, i'm new to Spring and Security. I am not writing production code. This is a learning project. So far you clued me in on the use of jwts and browsers. It is better used between server and server. Got it great but can you provide some thoughts to my scenario?

The CSRF chapter you linked to has advice on disabling CSRF which in turn links to an explanation of when to use CSRF protection. That explanation is intended to help you understand why you should not disable CSRF in browser-based applications.
In terms of configuring your application for CSRF, the page you linked has all the advice you need and you just need to follow it closely. However, adding your own custom JWT filter is inadvisable and will potentially cause problems like the one you are seeing if it is implemented incorrectly. Please see the OAuth2 Resource Server overview, which contains a section explaining how to use a custom JWT if you must use one. You do not need to implement your own JWT support.

NOTE: You can easily build an OAuth2-based solution with Spring Authorization Server that would be more beneficial to learn than supporting custom JWTs. Your backend services (APIs) would continue to be "stateless" in the way most people think of it.

Regardless, when you enable JWT support that comes with Spring Security's OAuth2 Resource Server, you should continue following advice in the CSRF chapter and leave CSRF protection enabled. There are several options there for correctly integrating your frontend with CSRF.

Thank you fro the guidance. I am actually following a udemy course on Spring Security 6 and this is what the course is recommending i.e, using tokens instead of JSESSIONIds. I did find that removing the STATLESS session management, kept the cookie static for the duration of the session. However I am also manually clearing the cookie. This seemed to alleviate the issues I was facing. Another point I'm curious about is that JWTs can be used on their own and can be leveraged with OAuth. But since I am not delegating authorization to a third party it doesn't fit my usecase. Does this make sense?

Out of curiosity, which udemy course are you following? Re: "Another point I'm curious about" I'm not sure I understand. Can you clarify what you mean by "it doesn't fit my usecase"? What specifically doesn't fit?

This is the course - https://www.udemy.com/course/spring-security-zero-to-master/

I am nog using a social login as described by the course like google or facebook so no need for OAuth yet.

Of course you can use OAuth2 without social login. You can also start with a custom JWT as I linked in the docs, and graduate to OAuth2 when you're ready (which I recommend). In any case, you don't need to implement custom filters, which unfortunately are often the source of bugs for beginners. I don't have a udemy subscription so I can't say why the teacher chooses to teach that concept in that way, but hopefully the OAuth2 section uses Spring Security's OAuth2 support at least.
